# C# Open.TK Mouse.GetState() missing

Tags: c#, opentk

I'm trying to get my mouse position in C# using open.TK, in my other classes it works fine with Mouse.GetState(); but in this class it is broken and asks if I'm missing an assembly reference despite using the same. Any idea why it isnt working ?

Part in question:

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Input;

public SceneManager()
    {
        //Mouse.ButtonDown += Mouse_ButtonDown;

        var mouse = Mouse.GetState();
        int x = mouse.X;
        int y = mouse.Y;
        int z = mouse.Wheel;
    }
```

Full Class

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Input;

namespace PongGame
{
    class SceneManager : GameWindow
{
    Scene scene;
    static int width = 0;
    static int height = 0;
    int tick = 0;
    public delegate void SceneDelegate(FrameEventArgs e);
    public SceneDelegate renderer;
    public SceneDelegate updater;

    public SceneManager()
    {
        //Mouse.ButtonDown += Mouse_ButtonDown;

        var mouse = Mouse.GetState();
        int x = mouse.X;
        int y = mouse.Y;
        int z = mouse.Wheel;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

        base.Width = 1024;
        base.Height = 512;
        SceneManager.width = Width;
        SceneManager.height = Height;

        scene = new MainMenuScene(this);
    }

    protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        updater(e);

    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);

        renderer(e);


        GL.Flush();
        SwapBuffers();

    }

   /* private void Mouse_ButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Button)
        {
            case MouseButton.Left:
                StartNewGame();
                break;
            case MouseButton.Right:
                StartMenu();
                break;
        }
    } */

    public void endGame(int scoreAI, int scorePlayer)
    {

        scene = new endGameScene(this, scoreAI, scorePlayer); 
    }
    public void StartNewGame()
    {
        scene = new GameScene(this);
    }

    public void StartMenu()
    {
        scene = new MainMenuScene(this);
    }

    public static int WindowWidth
    {
        get { return width; }
    }

    public static int WindowHeight
    {
        get { return height; }
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        GL.Viewport(ClientRectangle.X, ClientRectangle.Y, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
        SceneManager.width = Width;
        SceneManager.height = Height;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenTK is assuming `GameWindow.Mouse`, when you want `OpenTK.Input.Mouse`

Use:

```
var mouse = OpenTK.Input.Mouse.GetState();
int x = mouse.X;
int y = mouse.Y;
int z = mouse.Wheel;
```